# Calculating Area solar radiation gives ERROR 000732: output raster considered as Input?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, error-000732, solar-radiation

I am trying to calculate **Area solar radiation** for rasters in a list.

It seems that the tool allows to create unique rasters for direct, diffuse and direct radiation duration, and calculates `outGlobalRadiation` as the final output.

But, when I define the names for the `direct`, `diffuse` and `direct radiation duration` rasters, I got back an error `RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset dir_1 does not exist or is not supported` meaning, that my *optional* output file is actually considered as `Input Raster`, and does not exist.

Do you understand this error? Or is there any logical error in my script?

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

# Get path
inWD = "C:/Users/2019_bioESS_coord"

# Set working environment
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(inWD, "output/bufRastTwins.gdb")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# List all rasters
rasters= arcpy.ListRasters("r_*")


# Calculate solar radiation with defined optional outputs
for raster in rasters:

    # Define names for output optional rasters
    outNameDirect = "dir_" + raster.replace("r_", "")
    outNameDiff = "diff_" + raster.replace("r_", "")
    outNameDirDur = "dirDur_" + raster.replace("r_", "")

    # Define parameters for solar radiation
    in_surface_raster = raster
    latitude = ""
    skySize = 200
    timeConfig = TimeMultipleDays(2018, 100, 150)
    dayInterval = 10    # default 14
    hourInterval = 12   # default 0.5
    each_interval = "NOINTERVAL"  # "INTERVAL"
    zFactor = ""
    calcDirections = 32
    zenithDivisions = 8
    azimuthDivisions = 8
    diffuseProp = 0.3
    transmittivity = 0.5

    # Set names for optional output rasters, seems not working???
    outDirectRad = arcpy.Raster(outNameDirect)  
    outDiffuseRad = arcpy.Raster(outNameDiff)
    outDirectDur =  arcpy.Raster(outNameDirDur) 


    # Execute AreaSolarRadiation
    outGlobalRad = arcpy.sa.AreaSolarRadiation(in_surface_raster, latitude, skySize, timeConfig,
                                               dayInterval, hourInterval, each_interval, zFactor, "FROM_DEM" ,
                                               calcDirections, zenithDivisions, azimuthDivisions, "UNIFORM_SKY",
                                               diffuseProp, transmittivity,
                                               outDirectRad, outDiffuseRad, outDirectDur)

    print("area radiation saving")
    # Save the output 
    outGlobalRad.save(raster.replace("r_", "globRad_"))
```

Comment: Does "dir_1" exist? you are giving it as input to [`arcpy.Raster`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) apparently (in your line `outDirectRad = arcpy.Raster(outNameDirect)`) function which requires an input raster to be passed. If it does not exist, I guess it will simply fail.

Comment: No, it does not exists. Instead, I would like to create it as optional output data and define its name. Neither assesing the name as `outNameDirect = "dir_" + raster.replace("r_", "")`  or declaring it directly with the path works: `os.path.join(inWD, "output", outNameDirect)`. How could I declare it, that it is not considered as `Input` but as and `Output`? Seems trivial, but I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think to make your script work you should:

1. remove all the arcpy.Raster() calls

```
# Set names for optional output rasters, seems not working???
outDirectRad = arcpy.Raster(outNameDirect)  
outDiffuseRad = arcpy.Raster(outNameDiff)
outDirectDur =  arcpy.Raster(outNameDirDur)
```

2. change the call to `arcpy.sa.AreaSolarRadiation` like this:

```
# Execute AreaSolarRadiation
outGlobalRad = arcpy.sa.AreaSolarRadiation(in_surface_raster, latitude, skySize, timeConfig,
                                           dayInterval, hourInterval, each_interval, zFactor, "FROM_DEM" ,
                                           calcDirections, zenithDivisions, azimuthDivisions, "UNIFORM_SKY",
                                           diffuseProp, transmittivity,
                                           arcpy.Raster(outNameDirect), arcpy.Raster(outNameDiff), arcpy.Raster(outNameDirDur))
```

If it works, the reason is that [`arcpy.Raster`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/raster-object.htm) documentation reads that:

> A raster object can be created in two ways, by supplying the path to
>   an existing raster on disk, or it can be the result of any Map Algebra
>   statement that results in a raster output.

So, either you give an existent raster, or (as in your case) the input is generated by a function (internally I guess `arcpy.sa.AreaSolarRadiation` is doing this for you).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @umbe1987 but it still looks for raster `dir_1`. Also, I think that my script mimics ArcGIS help, where new rasters are created in the same way, and later included in `AreaSolarRadiation` tool: `outDirectDur = Raster("C:/sapyexamples/output/dir_dur")`, more here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/area-solar-radiation.htm. Do you maybe have another advices?

Comment: In the example in the link you provided I see they are referencing a full path, not just the name of the output raster. Try for instance calling `Raster(os.path.join(inWD, "output/bufRastTwins.gdb",outNameDirect))` (also fot the other two optional rasters), and see if it works.

Comment: Also, might be better to do `inWD = r"C:/Users/2019_bioESS_coord"` instead of `inWD = "C:/Users/2019_bioESS_coord"` (add the `r` in front of the path)